# Guardar Schema en un documento existente con Mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Estoy haciendo un CRUD con Nodejs, mongoDB, y un motor de plantilla.

Tengo un login con passport, al crear un usuario, quiero que cada producto que guarde desde el formulario, se guarde en el documento de su _id asignado por mongoDB al usuario.

Copio`router.post('/remember', isAuthenticated, async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.user._id;
  console.log( '=> ' +  id )
  const { frase, dia } = req.body;
  const user = new User({frase, dia})
  await user.save( { _id : id } );
  res.json({status: 'Task save'})
});`

En la liena user.save( { _id: id } ) indico que se debe de guardar en el _id correspondiente del usuario logeado, pero mongoDB me crea un nuevo ducmento en la colección y no lo guarda en el documento del id del usuario.

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias.

Salud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como primer punto, debes encontrar el registro con el `id` correspondiente, esto puedes hacerlo asi:

```
let user = await User.findById(id)
```

Despues puedes modificar los valores de ese registro:

```
user.frase = frase
user.dia = dia

await user.save()
```

Esto tambien puede lograrse en un solo query:

```
await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, {$set: { frase, dia } })
```

Una observacion mas, cuando quieres editar no usas **POST** pero usas **PATCH** o **PUT**.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no es para editar por eso utilizo POST, pero muchas gracias por esa info extra. Salud.